# Excel - Populate a row based on value of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to fill in a row based on a cell value. For example, if in cell A1 I enter 4, cell B1 to B4 will get filled with Deal 1, Deal 2, Deal 3, Deal 4. If I enter 2 in cell A1, then cell B1 and B2 will get filled with Deal 1, Deal 2.

Can this be done without macros?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B1 and copy down as many rows as you will ever want.

```
=IF(ROW()<=$A$1,"Deal " & ROW(),"")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! works perfectly. exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @MoonisAhmed please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only the one who asked the question can do.

Comment: Slight modification to my earlier question, what if I want to fill B1,C1,D1 with "Deal.." instead of B1,B2,B3?

Comment: @MoonisAhmed change both `ROW()` to `COLUMN(A:A)`

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF($A$1>= ROW(),"DEAL" & ROW(),"")
```

Copy above code to cell B1. Copy Cell B1 again then paste down to B4